# Performance improvments for Python large integer multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I'm working on a project that involves very large number multiplication due to taking the nth factorial of x where x is n 1s in a row.

The whole things work very efficiently, but I'm spending 80%+ of my computation time calculating the product of the integers for the factorial.

This bottleneck becomes especially noticeable at n = 7 where I effectively hit a brick wall. 6 takes under 0.1 seconds, 7 takes 7.5 seconds, and 8 takes so long I've stopped it after a few minutes without it completing.

Any way I can improve the efficiency of this? More specifically the efficiency of the math.prod(arr).

```
import argparse
import MyFormatter
import datetime
import math

def first_n_digits(num, n):
    return num // 10 ** (int(math.log(num, 10)) - n + 1)

start = datetime.datetime.now()  

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=MyFormatter.MyFormatter,
    description="Calcs x factorial",
    usage="",
)

parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.number == 1 :
    print(1)
    exit()

s = ""

for _ in range(0, args.number) :
    s = s + "1"
    n = 1

s = int(s)
arr = []

while (s > 1) :
    arr.append(s)
    s -= args.number

n = math.prod(arr)

fnd = str(first_n_digits(n,3))  
print("{}.{}{}e{}".format(fnd[0], fnd[1], fnd[2], int(math.log10(n))))

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print(end-start)
```

Comment: This kind of problem needs to be solved with smarter math, not faster brute force. You only need the order of magnitude and first 3 digits of the multifactorial, not the whole thing. You need to compute that information *without* computing the whole multifactorial.

Comment: This could help--[Blog post](https://jasonstitt.com/c-extension-n-choose-k) on improving the efficiency of computing factorials for large numbers.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Do you have any tips on where to start looking into how to compute this information?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an exact product. You just need 3 leading digits and an order of magnitude. You're wasting tremendous amounts of time and memory doing the computation in exact integer arithmetic.

One initial step would be to add up logarithms instead of multiplying integers:

```
log_prod = 0
while s > 1:
    log_prod += math.log10(s)
    s -= args.number

magnitude = int(log_prod)
normalized = 10**(log_prod-magnitude)
```

This discards millions of digits of precision you don't need, computing results in approximate floating-point arithmetic that still has enough precision for your use case. `normalized` is a number between 1 and 10 that has the same leading digits as the full product, and `magnitude` is the full product's order of magnitude.

This still has to add up a lot of logarithms as the input size increases, taking exponentially more time and losing more precision. Further steps might involve using a more sophisticated summation routine (helping with precision, but not runtime), or finding a different way to express the multifactorial that's more amenable to computation.

Comment: Those 3 downvotes in rapid succession seem pretty suspicious, and I see DeltaHaxor has a recent "-70: Voting corrected" in their rep history yesterday. I suspect sockpuppet votes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ill definetly keep this in mind, but Ill also look into other options so that I have the experience incase a situation comes up where I do need the full factorial .

Comment: @Kadragon: The full factorial will rapidly grow beyond the limits of your computer's ability to even store it, even if you could compute it instantly. It's already megabytes long for n=8, and the storage requirements grow exponentially with n.